# Probability of being dealt a straight in Poker

Tags: probability

> In poker, what is the probability of being dealt a straight?

### Attempt:

First, we find the size of sample space, the set of all possible 5-hand combinations, this is ${52 \choose 5}$. Now, in how many ways can we obtain a straight? So, this is my thinking,

1) For the first card, we have $14$ possibilities. Let's say we pick an ace. So the other cards must be 2,3,4, and 5.

Notice the ace can be chosen in 4 ways. Now, same argument works until first card is J since then we cant have straight. So we only have $11$ choices. Thus, we have that the number of ways to get straight is

$$ 11 \times 4 \times 14 $$

and hence,

$$ Probability \; \; = \frac{ 11 \times 4 \times 14 }{ {52 \choose 5 } } $$

Is this correct argument?

Comment: Note:  when poker players speak of "straights" they usually mean to exclude straight flushes and royal flushes.  (similarly, when they speak of three-of-a-kind they are excluding full houses and four-of -a-kind).

Comment: There are 13 possibilities.  An ace can be part of two straights (A,2,3,4,5) or (10,J,Q,K,A).  Also you need to get the other three cards.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability  gives answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your argument is not correct.

A [straight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Straight) is a poker hand consisting of five cards of sequential rank, not all of the same suit.

1. Choose the low card, which may be an ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
2. Choose the suits for each of the five cards in the hand, keeping in mind that a flush (all cards of the same suit) is not permitted.

> The number of favorable hands is $$10 \cdot (4^5 - 4)$$

Comment: Why are you deducting 4 from $$4^5$$?

Comment: @ilovetolearn  In poker, there is a distinction between a straight, five consecutive ranks not all of the same suit, and a straight flush, five consecutive ranks all of the same suit.  To ensure that not all cards of the same suit are chosen for the selected ranks, we must subtract the four cases in which a flush is obtained.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig where do you get the 10 from? in 1) you only have 9 numbers?

Comment: @Trajan There are nine numbers and an ace.